# R ggmaps not loading map

Tags: r, ggmap, stamen-maps

I'm new to R following an online tutorial. However, my attempt is failing  at a seemingly easy juncture:

```
coords.map <- get_stamenmap(map_bounds, zoom = 7, maptype = "toner-lite")
```

This command returns the error:

> could not find function get_stamenmap

I have tried some more 'get map' type commands and they seem to work, suggesting it is down to this particular code.

What is causing this error?

Comment: The `get_stamenmap` function is part of the [`ggmap`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/index.html) package. You must load it with `library(ggmap)`. If it is not yet installed, install it with `install.packages("ggmap")`.

Comment: precisely - sorry for the silly question. Thanks :)